# Fields for storing user passwords

Tags: database-design, schema, password

What coulmn heads would you need, generally speaking, for storing user passwords in a database, and what would be their datatypes be (irrespective of specific hashing/encryption algorithm used)?

One VARCHAR(x) for encrypted password and another for the salt?

Comment: You use hashing for passwords and not encryption.

Comment: Bespoke programming that requires manipulation of the salt as a separate field is an antipattern.. Instead, you also use a hash algorithm that automatically includes the salt as part of the hash itself (PBKDF2, bcrypt, etc.), and use standard libraries to hash passwords and verify them later.

Comment: `binary(32)` exactly fits a salted *and hashed* password of 256-bit hash length

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, what you're really look to store is a **hashed** representation of the password as opposed to **encryption** which is a type of security mechanism (somewhat minute difference though). In any case there's nothing special with using a `VARCHAR` vs any other data type that can store the **hashed** password correctly. Personally I've used `VARCHAR` before just fine.

As far as storing the salt, that is something I personally wouldn't store in the same table as the one where the passwords live. In my opinion, it's better to decouple that from the database all together, from a security standpoint. Whether that's statistically any more secure is beyond my scope of knowledge. But I would believe so since the salt *can* be a somewhat constant value that I would rather be stored separate from my database so if there was a breach, it's not being served on a silver platter with the hashed passwords. In the past, it was either part of the hashing library I was using in my application code, or at least stored in the application code itself (which has somewhat of a security risk but likely better than stored with the passwords in the database). I agree with Royce regarding using hashing algorithms like **PBKDF2**, **bcrypt**, or my personal choice is **Argon2**.

As far as column names go, I don't think it makes much of a difference in obscuring the password field's name since someone with a copy of the data can still easily search for the fields with hash-like values, which will presumably be in a `Users` (or similarly named) table anyway. And even additionally obscuring the table name still doesn't help much because again, it's easy to find the hashed columns rather quickly too.

For further recommendations from a security standpoint, I'd recommend asking specific questions on [Crypto.StackExchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) and [Security.StackExchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/).